# When to change Timing belt - Peugeot 307 2003 1.6cc

Tags: timing-belt, peugeot

I have got a Peugeot  307 2003 1.6cc

Current milage is 97,000 and last full service had been done when on 60,000.

I had done my MOT recently there were no major issues.

I was wandering when should I change the Timing belt? And does MOT check Timing belt's condition ?

Comment: I removed the average cost part of the question as it's off-topic here, but the rest of your question is valid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know if the belt has already been changed, and if so, at what mileage? If it hasn't been done, I'd suggest it is worth doing - they usually need it at between 80 and 100k - the correct interval should be in your handbook.

No, the MOT doesn't check the condition - You can't generally check it without dismantling anything, as it's usually hidden behind a cover, and behind the auxiliary belts. The MOT tester isn't allowed to remove any covers or dismantle anything during the test

Comment: I don't see a record in service history . I checked with Peugeot dealer they said they had last seen this car in 2013 . I bought when it was 95+ miles , 2years back( my first car ! , so hope you can imagine :) ) . wondering is it worth to change this or sell and get a low milage same model car.

Comment: It sounds like it needs changing then. Whether to change or to sell is down to your budget, and whether you are happy with the rest of the car. Changing it at an independent garage shouldn't cost much more than £300-400, most of which is labour... It's a perfectly DIY-able job, but not one I'd recommend if you don't have much experience of working on cars...

Comment: thank you . similar budget to this car , around 1200. I got these advisory items with recent MOT,
001 Nearside front Suspension arm ball joint dust cover deteriorated, but preventing the ingress of dirt [2.4.0.2] 
002 Front (both side) Suspension arm rubber bush deteriorated but not resulting in excessive movement [2.4.0.2] 
003 Front (both) brake disc worn, pitted or scored, but not seriously weakened [3.5.1i] 004 Offside rear Shock absorber has a slightly worn linkage [2.7.4] 005 Under-trays fitted obscuring some underside components 006 Play in steering rack inner joint(s) .

Comment: None of those sound particularly worrying...

Comment: I see, thank you . In that case seems like worth replacing the timing belt and stick with it. Just got a quote from Peugeot dealer (R & D) £345